# Kong Docker with Non-Docker Postgres

Tags: docker, kong

I’m currently using Kong on Debian (native installation).
I’d like to move Kong into docker, but the database using existing Postgres (non-docker), and also use configuration from existing /etc/kong/kong.conf.

How to achieve this? In [docker installation guide](https://docs.konghq.com/install/docker/), there’s only instruction to use docker Postgres.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure following environment variables to tell Kong where your Postgres database is and how to connect to it:

```
- KONG_DATABASE
- KONG_PG_HOST
- KONG_PG_PORT
- KONG_PG_USER
- KONG_PG_PASSWORD
- KONG_PG_DATABASE
```

Description of each variable can be found in [postgres settings documentation](https://docs.konghq.com/1.0.x/configuration/#postgres-settings).

You pass environment variable to container using `-e` option. Example of modified docker run command from docker installation guide:

```
 $ docker run -d --name kong \
   --network=kong-net \
   -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
   -e "KONG_PG_HOST=127.0.0.1" \
   -e "KONG_PG_PORT=5432" \
   -e "KONG_PG_USER=kong" \
   -e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong" \
   -e "KONG_PG_DATABASE=kong" \
   -e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
   -e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
   -e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
   -e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
   -e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl" \
   -p 8000:8000 \
   -p 8443:8443 \
   -p 8001:8001 \
   -p 8444:8444 \
   kong:latest
```

According to [Kong configuration documentation](https://docs.konghq.com/1.0.x/configuration/#environment-variables) you can override every variable from `kong.conf` file using environment variable:

> When loading properties out of a configuration file, Kong will also look for environment variables of the same name. This allows you to fully configure Kong via environment variables, which is very convenient for container-based infrastructures, for example.
>
> To override a setting using an environment variable, declare an environment variable with the name of the setting, prefixed with `KONG_` and capitalized.